# CSRF mismatch when POSTing to sails backend from Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, sails.js

In angular, I obtain a CSRF token like this:

```
// Get CSRF token and set as header
var csrfRequest = Auth.getCSRF().then(function(data){
    console.log(data.data._csrf);
    $rootScope.csrf = data.data._csrf;
});
```

Which logs the new token to the console (this works fine).

Then, I try to login to a sails.js api. Here's the request:

```
POST /auth/login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1337
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 108
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.99 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost/sails-front/src/login/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6

Request Payloadview parsed
    {"email":"myemail@email.com","password":"mypass","_csrf":"PIlVO7S362OroPGBSG0X1vW2FydkP9VhK8cMk="}
```

The `_csrf` field is the same as that which was received in the `getCSRF` call.

Yet I get the response 'CSRF mismatch'. However, when I try the exact same thing with Postman, it works fine (so I don't think it's a problem with the sails server).

Here's the login code in angular. In the controller:

```
$scope.login = function() {
    Auth.login({
            email: $scope.email,
            password: $scope.password,
            _csrf: $rootScope.csrf
        },
        function(res) {
            $state.go('app.home');
        },
        function(err) {
            $rootScope.error = "Failed to login";
        });
};
```

And the `Auth` service:

```
/*********************************
* login
******************************** */
function login(user, success, error) {
    $http.post(API_BASE_URL + 'auth/login', user).success(function(user){
        changeUser(user);
        success(user);
    }).error(error);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You posted your full request, and the answer is hidden there in plain sight--not by looking at what is being sent, but what is being *omitted*: namely, the cookie.  The CSRF token is valid for a single Sails session, but you are neglecting to send the cookie with your AJAX request, so Sails has no idea which session the CSRF token you're sending is for.

To tell Angular to send cookies with your request, use the `withCredentials` setting:

`$http.post(API_BASE_URL + 'auth/login', user, {withCredentials: true})`

Comment: I am doing this and still doesn't work. I get `CSRF Mismatch`

Comment: If i set it with `$http.defaults.withCredentials = true;` it works, but i do need it in a specific post, not in general.

Comment: @JuanSolano not sure what to tell you...works for me and is correct according to the [Angular docs for $http.post](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)...

Comment: I tried all of these solutions and they didn't work. I'm currently doing a GET request on `/csrftoken` and saving that value and using it for the requests. I intercept all the POST and DELETE requests and add the token.