# SailsJS CSRF mismatch after logout AND getting new /csrfToken

Tags: node.js, websocket, sails.js, csrf

I'm creating Single Page Application. I've created login-logout actions and they work fine. But if user logs out and will not refresh page in browser, he couldn't log in again because of "CSRF mismatch" error.

Steps:

1. At first page load, csrf is view local:

```
<div class="app" id="app" data-csrf="<%= _csrf %>"></div>
```

2. User logs in with this token successfully:

```
420["post",{"method":"post","headers":{},"data":{"_csrf":"VHcT2F44-KhZMJmhcAVB1H69BgTMWMZji9_8","login":"alex","password":"123"},"url":"http://127.0.0.1:1337/login"}]
430[{"body":{"id":"560e5756cd01633407eea8be"},"headers":{cut headers},"statusCode":200}]
```

3. Then, user logs out with this token:

```
421["post",{"method":"post","headers":{},"data":{"_csrf":"VHcT2F44-KhZMJmhcAVB1H69BgTMWMZji9_8"},"url":"http://127.0.0.1:1337/logout"}]
431[{"body":"ok","headers":{cut headers},"statusCode":200}]
```

4. And if he try to log in again, he will catch "CSRF mismatch" error and I expected that:

```
422["post",{"method":"post","headers":{},"data":{"_csrf":"VHcT2F44-KhZMJmhcAVB1H69BgTMWMZji9_8","login":"alex","password":"123"},"url":"http://127.0.0.1:1337/login"}]
432[{"body":"CSRF mismatch","headers":{},"statusCode":403}]
```

5. I'm catching this error and doing /csrfToken request as said in [docs](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/security/csrf)

```
423["get",{"method":"get","headers":{},"data":{},"url":"/csrfToken"}]
433[{"body":{"_csrf":"49C5OVUZ-6SIL_zW3g1NGI87ux6Mlp-UJj_w"},"headers":{cut headers},"statusCode":200}]
```

6. Trying to log in again with new token:

```
424["post",{"method":"post","headers":{},"data":{"_csrf":"49C5OVUZ-6SIL_zW3g1NGI87ux6Mlp-UJj_w","login":"alex","password":"123"},"url":"http://127.0.0.1:1337/login"}]
434[{"body":"CSRF mismatch","headers":{},"statusCode":403}]
```

I could repeat steps 5 and 6 with same result.

If I refresh page, I can log in without errors.
Question is, what's going on? Why token mismatch at step 6?

Edit: logout method:

```
req.session.destroy();
return res.send("ok");
```

Edit 2: sending request:

```
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';
import sailsIOClient from 'sails.io.js';
var io = sailsIOClient(socketIOClient);

io.socket.post(form.action, serialize(form, {hash: true}), function (data, jwres){
...
});
```

Comment: How are you implementing your `logout` action?

Comment: Added logout source code to post

Comment: Could not reproduce this.  How are you sending your AJAX requests?  Is it with Angular `$http`?  Are you sending the request using `withCredentials` so that the cookies are sent (and the correct session is retrieved?).  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28225843/345484

Comment: @sgress454 I'm sending requests with built-in sails.io.js (added information in post). I'm sure cookies are sent because before logout all requests work fine. I'll prepare example git-repository today or tomorrow maybe. Thanks for help.

Comment: @sgress454 please check https://github.com/frutality/sails-example (problem is in req.session.destroy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR:  Use `req.session.csrfSecret = null` instead of `req.session.destroy()` if you're doing everything over sockets.

---

The issue here is with the way [Express sessions](https://github.com/expressjs/session) work.  When you call `.destroy()` on one, it removes the entry for the current session ID (SID) in the `sessions` object that Express MemoryStore maintains.  Normally that's fine because it will be regenerated on the next request, but that's only the next request *that runs all of the Express middleware*--and Socket requests to a Sails app don't do that, as [anyone trying to use Passport with Sails out-of-the-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973959/why-is-req-user-undefined-for-socket-requests-in-sails-js-angular-js-and-pass) will tell you.  So the next time you make a socket request (to generate a new CSRF secret and get a new token), you're not actually connected to a session and the new info doesn't get saved.

If instead of destroying the whole session, you just destroy the `csrfSecret` which is used to generate CSRF tokens, then the next socket request will still be attached to a session and the new secret will be saved.  You'll also want to blank out any other session variables that were keeping the user logged in.

Comment: Thank you fo explanation, I think I get it. Just made a quick test and everything works fine.

Comment: One more question. Why can't we just use `req.session = null`? I've tried it and logout did't work. I was still logged in.

Comment: `req.session` is a _reference_ to a value in the Express session middleware's `sessions` object.  When you set `req.session` to `null`, it doesn't actually set the whole session object to null: it just breaks that reference.  Besides, if it were `null` you'd lose the `cookie` key and you'd be back where you started.  The closest thing would be to loop over all of the keys in `req.session` and delete them, but make sure to leave `cookie` there or you'll have the same problem as before!